# Why is webhook send json into InputStream instead of action parameter of asp.net controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

There is some payment service that is send webhook. In this response must be some json string.

Actual: Don't have any string in action parameter of controller. But json received in InputStream of response.

Expected: Have json in action parameter.

Comment: You will need to really expand on what the problem is and what you are wanting to achieve. Adding code samples will also help.

Comment: There are not any sample code because it's default asp.net mechanism to get webhook response to controller's action. So I want to know what is related to have response in inputstream instead of default parse to action parameter.